# In ffmpeg, how to set "-option reserve_index_space=1k"?

Tags: ffmpeg, webm

I want to reserve a bit of space for the index in my webm files. `reserve_index_space` seems to do that, but how do you use it?

I tried `-option reserve_index_space=1k`, but it said:

```
Unrecognized option 'option'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

It's mentioned here: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Options-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `-reserve_index_space 1k`. It goes after all the inputs and before the output filename.

Comment: It works when -reserve_index_space 1k is used. Remove the equal sign.